# Django: Dynamic url not expanding in Template tags

Tags: ajax, django

**UPDATE**
See my answer below. I got it to work. But I am not sure if that is elegant way.

**ORIGINAL**

I have an Ajax call which returns link to load data from.

```
if (data.verified == 1) {
    var link = "{% data.target_link %}"; 
    alert(link)
    $('#my-modal').load(link);

}
```

In view I set url like this:

```
url = "url 'health:add_doctors_staff' " + doctor_id
```

I also tried

```
var link = data.target_link;
```

and

```
url = "{% url 'health:add_doctors_staff' " + doctor_id + " %}"
```

But it is not working. It seems Django template is not able to expand the url received from Ajax. How can I fix this issue. I don't want to send expanded(partially harcoded) url from the Ajax call view.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Works after I changed the url variable to `url = "/add_doctors_staff/" + doctor_id`

and in Ajax part: 
`var link = data.target_link;`